# Web app development - what are documentation best practices

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, document

I am building a web app for learning purposes using HTML, PHP, jQuery and MySQL. As my app is getting bigger and is having more and more interactions, I am starting to get confused and messy. Thus, I would like to know what are the best practices to document a web app: methodologies, software, etc.

Comment: Best practices?  **Doing it** is a pretty good practice... just keep doing that :P

Comment: Always comment the code and may use something like phpdoc

Comment: "best pratice" is often used as a way of pushing through personal opinion. I know I use that strategy - I consider it best practice. Please rephrase the question with a more specific issue, the things you've tried/considered, and ways of evaluting a response.

Comment: This is a bit broad for StackOverflow - too discursive. See the FAQ `:)`. But, fwiw, framework + version control + project management is a good start.

Comment: One should mention here too that this question is not a very good fit for the [so] format.  This question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion.

Comment: Sorry. I did not know that those question is to avoid. I Will Digg into php doc blocks as mentionned by several people...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use strict PHPDoc blocks in all your classes and methods, and then use Reflection to create documentation on the fly.

Comment: Hello Aliéné. Thks for thé reply . What is réfection?

Comment: Reflection is an API which allows your script to fetch information about itself. It is built into PHP, docs here: http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php. Here is an overview of the process for creating documentation on the fly: http://www.murraypicton.com/2011/01/using-the-php-reflection-api-to-document-your-code/

Comment: I Will read about that à little and revert